# Forcing an application to use a specific resolution in windows xp guest on ubuntu host, virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, virtualbox

I have installed a game (football manager 11) on my windows xp guest os on my ubuntu 10.10 ubuntu host using virtual box.The problem is that the game starts at a higher resolution and i cant see the whole screen in my 800X600 windows xp resolution. Is there anyway i can force the game to use 800X600 resolution before starting it ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: That is a game dependent setting, I'd rather try to setup virtual box to rescale the guest such that it fits your screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the shortcut -> Compatibility -> Start in 640x480